# I want to use Values getting from custom middleware in my service class constructor of FeathersJS

Tags: node.js, express, feathersjs

I have following custom middleware in my feathersjs project.

```
const { envConfig } = require('url-config');

module.exports.envCfg = function (options = {}) {
    return async function () {
        const config = await envConfig('mongodb://localhost:27017', 'dbname');
    }
}
```

I want to use `config` from my middleware in one of service constructor. I also have 1 method in my `require('url-config')` which returns same value but since code inside my `envConfig` is executed asynchronously and It has to be called during app start only I cant get it in service.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to add it to your `app` instance. You can copy how feathers do the `app.configure()`.

```
module.exports = async function(){
    app = this;

    app.envConfig = await envConfig('mongodb://localhost:27017', 'dbname');
}
```